# Get image minimum width within folder

Tags: jquery

How do I get the minimum width of images that are in a folder `"images/list"`?

The folder has different sized images and I just want the minimum width so as to set all images and display a proper layout on page.

**HTML**:

```
<div>
<img class="minimg" src="images/list/one.jpg" />
<img class="minimg" src="images/list/abc.jpg" />
<img class="minimg" src="images/list/xyz.jpg" />
<img class="minimg" src="images/list/two.jpg" />
<img class="minimg" src="images/list/apple.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.minimg{
    min-width:300px;
}
```

I want set all images by the minimum width of an image listed in folder using jQuery, how do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guss what you would like to do is something like this:

```
var minWidth = Math.min.apply( null,
        $('.minimg').map(function(){return $(this).width();}).get());
$('.minimg').width(minWidth);
```

JSFiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/z5x9R/1/

The document of `Math.min()` is here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min
And `Math.max.apply()` is here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This could work

```
var min_width = 0;
$('.minimg').each(function(){
  if (min_width == 0 || min_width > $(this).width())
    min_width = $(this).width();
});
$('.minimg').css({ "width" : min_width + "px"});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QdLUQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use javascript for this, iterate over all the images and store the value of the smallest one, then set the css for each image trough javascript.